# Какие есть варианты соединения элементов списка?

Tags: python

```
a = ['lloo']
b = []

for i in a:
    for k in i:
        if k == 'l':
            k = 'L'
        b.append(k)

b = [''.join(b[:])
```

Есть вариант сделать без повторного обращения к b, чтоб сразу ['LLoo'] вывелось?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пересоберите список с заменой через `replace` строковой `l` на `L`

```
a = ['lloo']
b = [c.replace('l', 'L') for c in a]  # ['LLoo']
```